# CSS is not loaded properly for on the Developer Story and CV pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Story and CV link CSS is disturbed. Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! This should be fixed now. :)